# How to see all registry changes of chosen application in C#

Tags: c#, registry

Hi there lovely StackOverFlow helpers, I got into a bit trouble recently.
I need to make an application in WinForm C# as my final programming project. The project is about managing Registry more nicely to make it easier for the user to edit values.

So what I need is; to show all the Registry values of the same type, to show what the value does and to show their build. For instance: the hierarchical build is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Keyboard Layout\Preload` and the key `1` controls the keyboard loadout when your pc first starts (about presenting it, I'll probably use RichTextBox for the graphical way or something else I'll figure out).
So I assume there's a way the data is placed in the Registry, like all of the setting of the app is here and the prefrences is there..

I hope I was clear enough, thanks for all of your time to read and answer it!! I really REALLY appreciate the effort!

Comment: A database for what every registry key and value does? You'd have to build one. Some of those keys are older than Windows With Networking...

Comment: So it means I need to put every single possible app out there to make it? Or it has some sort of an order it's placed there, so I can say "all the keys here does that and all the keys there does this"

Comment: The Registry is made up of things called "hives." That should tell you something. There is only the barest minimum of rhyme or reason to it and there is no central repository of information or documentation about it. On the bright side, your application will be *really* useful application if you can build it (and keep it up to date).